# MySQL function with variable parameter

Tags: mysql, function, parameters, jasper-reports, icinga

I am creating a monitoring report with iReport from Jaspersoft and data from icinga. 
In ireport I have to enter the query to get the data I need. Now, I want to get the name (of a monitored object) and the corresponding availability from that service. For this, icinga provides a [function](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga-reports/blob/master/db/icinga/mysql/availability.sql) which takes the object_id, a start date and an end date as parameters. Such as this:

```
select icinga_availability(203, '2017-09-01 00:00:00','2017-09-30 23:59:59'), name1 from icinga_objects where object_id = '203';
```

For iReport I need to get all needed objects in one single query. For example I need object number 131, 258, 101, 465.

Is it possible to pass a variable/wildcard or multiple object_ids into the function? I couldn't manage it yet.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iReport isn't officialy supported anymore, so it would be the best to switch to Jaspersoft Studio.

So I can only tell how it works in JSS, but it should work in iReport too:

```
select icinga_availability( $P{obejct_id} , '2017-09-01 00:00:00','2017-09-30 23:59:59'), name1 from icinga_objects where object_id = to_char( $P{obejct_id} );
```

Using an Integer-Parameter:

```
<parameter name="obejct_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

So when running the report, you can enter the object_id you want to view.